# Does SignalR client receive unsubscribed messages?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

If I have a signalR hub that sends messages to all clients with a fairly large payload or private information, do all clients that connect into the hub (part of the same group) receive the messages even though they don't subscribe to those events on the client side?

Wondering if the client is smart enough to negotiate what events it has to the server so the server doesn't send extraneous data?

Thanks!

Comment: You should mark the answer as the right answer since it is a complete answer

Answer (score 5):

Yes they do.  If a client is subscribed to a hub it will receive all messages sent through that hub's broadcasting channels.

There is no way to prevent the client from getting a message other than sending to a specific group that does not include the client or sending to another client specifically.

Some examples:

```
Clients.All.foo(); // All subscribed clients will foo invoked
Clients.Group("bar").foo(); // All subscribed clients to the hubs group "Bar" will have foo invoked.  If your client is not subscribed to "bar" it will not have "foo" invoked.
Clients.Client("AClientsConnectionId").foo(); // The client with the specified connection id will have foo invoked.
```