Is there any way NOT to receive all messages?
We are using @microsoft/signalr (quite sure this is not frotnend-specific though)
To subscribe calling hubConnection.on('header1', ...) and to send hubConnection.invoke('header1', ...) getting messages quite successfully.
But in dev-tools network I can see messages with other headers.
Question: Does everything work as intended? I can imagine that 1000 users making 1 save each gonna receive 1000 message each, 1 million total. I thought that signalr hub will send client only certain messages client requested for.

It sounds like, in your hub, you are responding to all clients. There are a variety of options to send to but these 2 will give you a good idea: "All" - Calls a method on all connected clients. "Caller" - Calls a method on the client that invoked the hub method.
Caller is the way to only send back to the client that called the method. This way, no matter who calls the method in the hub, they only get a response back to them. So, 1000 users making 1 save each would only response 1 time to the originating caller.

And that's all fine in the case of a user saving something only they see reflected. When  you start talking about the content of what each user is saving. Is user A supposed to also see saves from User B and so on. Hard to say since we don't have context here.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992705/does-signalr-client-receive-unsubscribed-messages?rq=2 so I guess my question is kinda duplicate.. Thats sad new though(
